# Merging Raster: ImportError: No module named _gdal_array

Tags: qgis, raster

When I try to merge rasters I got following error message:

> _gdal_array = swig_import_helper() File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py",
>   line 18, in swig_import_helper import _gdal_array ImportError: No
>   module named _gdal_array

I tried to update Qgis to 2.2 and did a the whole OS4GEOW installation, as recommended in an other thread.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your OSGEO4W installation is not install correctly. I had something similar and uninstalled OSGEO4W, deleted the .qgis2 folder and deleted all QGIS entries in Windows registry database. Then reinstall...

An alternative approach will be creating a virtual raster. Menu Raster > Miscellaneous > Build Virtual Raster (Catalog).

Comment: Thanks!I am working with the virtual raster at the moment, but is there a more simple solution? I installed OSGEO4W yesterday, but no changes...